# Ubuntu 12.04 KDE, Kmix - how to set audio 2.1 surround profile output

Tags: sound, kde

I installed KDE in ubuntu 12.04. In gnome I could choose audio profile method 4.1 that worked well for my 2.1 system, but now with Kmix I can't find it? How to set 2.1. If I set simple "analog stereo output" I'm not able to hear subwoofer and songs listening is different from windows 7.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Hardware -> Multimedia -> Phonon:

[image]

Or install `pavucontrol` package and start `pavucontrol`.

Comment: Thanks, but I went to phono from kmix and there I can't find the 2.1 hardware profile as I said on top.
But pavucontrol worked, I found 4.1 output like in gnome. But now i don't know if it works, in kmix now I can see 4.1 output but subwoofer doesn't work on press. thanks

Comment: how to add 2.1 to configuration?

Comment: sorry, i don't know why 2.1 is not available